# Modifying the source code of PMD

Tags: eclipse-plugin, pmd

I want to modify the source code of PMD, but I don't know how to compile and use this modifying PMD with Eclipse as a plug-in.

I read this [Compiling PMD instruction](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.3.2/customizing/compiling.html) but I didn't understand it very well.
can you help me please?

My Eclipse platform version: 4.3.2
PMD version: pmd-src-5.4.1
Operating System: windows 7